# Conditionally combining two observables

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs, observable, frp

Need to combine the following two observables:

- `observable1` emits `{ x: value1 }`
- `observable2` emits `{ y: value2 }`

into `observable3` that emits:

- `{ x: value1, y: value2 }` when `observable1` fires (`value2` is the last value emitted by `observable2`)
- `{ y: value }` when `observable2` fires

In other words, it should behave like `combineLatest` for `observable1` emits and like `merge` for `observable2` emits.

Is there an elegant-ish way to do this?

Comment: `Rx.Observable.merge(observable1.withLatestFrom(observable2), observable2)`?

Comment: You could implement your own operator.

Comment: @user3743222 thanks, that's it! Turns out, it's pretty simple. If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do :

```
observable3 = Rx.Observable.merge(observable1.withLatestFrom(observable2), observable2)
```

Note that `combineLatest` would not work here, as it would wait for `observable2` to produce a value. `withLatestFrom` is taken the latest value from `observable2` without the wait.

I also recommend you to test for the edge cases :

- `observable2` has not emitted any value yet (`withLatestFrom` might block and wait, it is not clear from the documentation)
- `observable2` has completed prior to your creating `observable3`